# Can user see the fetched documents using devtools?

Tags: javascript, security, document

If I am fetching user documents to just show profile Image to the unauthorized user. Will he somehow be able to see the whole document using dev tools.

Comment: The user can potentially see any communication from the back-end to the front-end (or vice versa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in Chrome you can see all network requests and their response data in the devtools network tab.

As said before in the comments, an user can see all communication between him and the server.

The frontend shouldn't be responsible for securing the backend, the backend should never send data in a response that the user isn't authorized for in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Ctrl+Shift+I, Network tab - there is all communication Client/Server. Also you can switch between subtabs in order to categorize them resorce types.